# "be better off" vs "would rather"

Tags: grammar

Be better off could be used to express that something is better than another. For instance,

> I would be better off driving insead instead of taking a bus.

Can we say

> I would rather drive than take a bus?

with the same meaning? So, my question is about differences and grammar of this structures.

Comment: The two expressions mean completely different things, as should be obvious if you consult any dictionary. You might *rather* eat junk food, but you'd be *better off* eating a healthy diet.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, it shouldn't because I looked up it in dictionaries. What I've understood is that we can use would rather when we're talking about something that is more preffered than another.

Comment: [To be better off](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/better-off) *- to be in a better situation, if or after something happens*. [Rather](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rather) *more readily or willingly :  preferably <I'd rather not go> <would rather read than watch television> —often used interjectionally to express affirmation*. The difference between personal "preference" and objective "improvement" seems quite clear to me, and I'd have thought that distinction could easily be made in any language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok, I got that. But can we say _it would be better off driving instead of taking the bus to me_? Is it incorrect/ungrammatical?

Comment: No, you can't use "existential 'it'" like that. It would have to be *"I/you/he/we/etc. would be better off [doing this rather than that]"*. But I think these type of questions are better suited to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Better off* implies that something would be more beneficial to the subject, whereas *would rather* has a connotation of personal preference.

For example, one could say:
"I **would rather** skip my chores and watch a movie, but I'd **be better off** if I did them right now."

Comment: So, it's not quite clear about a difference between _be better off_ and _should have + pp_ in a case like _I should have driven_ and _I would have been better off driving_. Both structures describe beneficials to tthe subject.

Comment: @St.Antario "Should" implies obligation and/or something beneficial, while "being better off" pretty much only addresses benefit to the subject. (So: "I *should* donate more money to charity, but I'd *be better off* if I put it in my savings.")

"Should have" and "being better off" can also be used interchangeably--"I should have driven" and "I would have been better off driving" have the same meaning.